# ATM Program Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I submitted this code for a simple ATM program in python. I got full credit but was told not to use global variables as they are considered bad programming. I've tried rewriting this function a million times, but when I do my balance isn't updating. Can someone show me what I'm doing wrong? It's bothering me that I can't figure it out myself!

My original:

```
name=input("Name on your bank account? ")
balance=float(input("Your current balance? "))

def printMenu():
    print(name,"Welcome to the Lots of Money Bank")
    print("Enter 'b'(balance), 'd'(deposit), 'w'(withdraw), or'q'(quit)")

def getTransaction():
    transaction=str(input("What would you like to do? "))
    return transaction

def withdraw(bal,amt):
    global balance
    balance=bal-amt
    if balance<0:
        balance=balance-10

def formatCurrency(amt):
    return "$%.2f" %amt

###MAIN PROGRAM###

printMenu()
command=str(getTransaction())

while command!="q":
    if (command=="b"):
        print(name,"Your current balance is",formatCurrency(balance))
        printMenu()
        command=str(getTransaction())
    elif (command=="d"):
        amount=float(input("Amount to deposit? "))
        balance=balance+amount
        printMenu()
        command=str(getTransaction())
    elif (command=="w"):
        amount=float(input("Amount to withdraw? "))
        withdraw(balance,amount)
        printMenu()
        command=str(getTransaction())
    else:
        print("Incorrect command. Please try again.")
        printMenu()
        command=str(getTransaction())

print(name,"Goodbye! See you again soon")
```

My edited withdraw function:

```
def withdraw(bal,amt):
    bal=balance
    amt=amount
    if(bal<0):
        bal=bal-10
    else:
        bal=bal-amt
    return bal

and my edited elif
elif (command=="w"):
        amount=float(input("Amount to withdraw? "))
        withdraw(balance,amount)
        printMenu()
        command=str(getTransaction())
```

Comment: In the elif you need bal = withdraw(balance, amount) -- right now you're just ignoring withdraw's return value!  (Many other smells in that code but this is the specific mistake you're asking about).

Answer (score 1):

You never update the "global" `balance` using the returned amount from `withdraw`...

Try this:

```
# and my edited elif
elif (command=="w"):
        amount=float(input("Amount to withdraw? "))
        # update balance!
        balance = withdraw(balance,amount)
        printMenu()
        command=str(getTransaction())
```

Also,

```
def withdraw(bal,amt):
    # 'balance' is bound to global balance - we don't want to use that
    # this is why we have 'bal' (passed through parameters)
    # bal = balance # no need, bal=balance when function is called
    # amt=amount    # same as balance
    if(bal<0):
        bal=bal-10
    else:
        bal=bal-amt
    return bal
```

Make sure you understand what are the scopes for the different parameters in your program.

Comment: Thank you SO much! I knew it was something painfully obvious that I just couldn't see!

Comment: This is a great answer. I will add on that it is also good practice to never have variables that are not grouped into classes as attributes. For your example, I would do something like: 
    class G():
       name=input("Name on your bank account? ")
       balance=float(input("Your current balance? "))
And access via G.balance and G.name
You could imagine how this could easily be expanded into a more detailed bank account object class (and if a function requires multiple attributes, you can pass the whole instance rather than variable by variable).

Answer (score 1):

In the `withdraw()` function you should not refer to the global variables `balance` and `amount`. Only `balance` needs to be updated when the function is called so we have:

```
def withdraw(bal,amt):
    if(bal<0):
        bal=bal-10
    else:
        bal=bal-amt
    return bal
```

and

```
elif (command=="w"):
        amount=float(input("Amount to withdraw? "))
        balance = withdraw(balance,amount)
        printMenu()
        command=str(getTransaction())
```